# How to continue timer( setTimeout() ) when app is exited or device is turned restarted using javascript in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, timer

im working on a cordova application that enables users schedule messages to be automatically sent later. i have been able to schedule messages successfully using javascript setTimeout(), but my problem is when i close my app or restart my device, the messages dont deliver( like the setTimeout() clears). what can i do to keep the timer running even after the app is close or i restart my device. i have tried background mode but that only work if the app is in the background and not entirely closed... i want to be able to run my timer even when the app is close or device is restarted... Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make background running application then it will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

[Cordova plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) to prevent the app from going to sleep while in background.

Most mobile operating systems are multitasking capable, but most apps dont need to run while in background and not present for the user. Therefore they pause the app in background mode and resume the app before switching to foreground mode. The system keeps all network connections open while in background, but does not deliver the data until the app resumes.

Command to install the plugin in your application

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git
```

Prevent the app from going to sleep in background

To prevent the app from being paused while in background, the backroundMode.enable interface has to be called.

Further informations

> The background mode will be activated once the app has entered the
>   background and will be deactivated after the app has entered the
>   foreground. To activate the background mode the app needs to be in
>   foreground.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```